# How to modify color scale values to smaller increments

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I have a map of the Nova Scotian coast. I want to average temperature per month across the ocean. The difference across months is about 0.01 degrees. The min and max ave_temp is 1.18-1.6. so my dataframe would like so

```
month    ave temp

may       1.18
may       1.18
jun       1.19
jul       1.20
jul       1.20
jan       1.60
jan       1.60
dec       1.52
nov       1.51
```

so when I plot a color gradient across the ocean using these temperatures there is hardly any difference across maps

this is the code I'm trying to use

```
p + geom_rect(data = individual_dets, 
mapping = aes(xmin = -62.8, xmax = -64.5, ymin = 42.7, ymax = 45, 
fill = individual_dets$ave_temp)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", mid = "red", high = "purple")
```

but I get the colors in the attached picture... as you can see hardly any difference. Is there anyway to make more of a gradient with small increments

[image]

Comment: Hi Kristen, what is p? and why are the rows of individual_dets duplicated?

Comment: You could try using the `limits` argument in `scale_fill_gradient2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax  cannot be identical across different rectangles, if you want to see one color for each rectangle. If they are all same, you are just plotting one rectangle with one fill colors. You may be using different facets to see different rectangles, but that is hard to tell without knowing your full code.

Below example works without any issues, when the xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax, with the same colors provided.

```
library(tidyverse)
c<- c(1.18,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.20, 1.60, 1.60, 1.52,1.51)
df <- expand.grid(x = (1:3), y = (1:3))
df$ave_temp <- c(1.18,1.18,1.19,1.20,1.20, 1.60, 1.60, 1.52,1.51)

ggplot() + geom_rect(data = df, 
                     aes(xmin = x-0.4,xmax = x + 0.4, 
                         ymin = y-0.4, ymax = y + 0.4, 
                         fill = df$ave_temp) )+  
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "yellow", mid = "red", high = "purple")
```

which produces the following figure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping like this:
you have colour wheel,

[image: colour wheel]

which you stretch over line and every vertical column (that used to be a wedge) is different colour representing one degree and every row in that column shaded by brightness would represent fraction of degree. If your changes are small you can use every colour as fraction of degree and shades as fraction of fraction.

In HSV colour space

[image: hsv colour space]

degrees would be `hue` and fractions would be `value` or saturation for that matter.